# What are some of the factors that affect loan pricing?

Tags: loans, credit

In an interview for a bank, I was asked about some of the factors that could affect loan pricing.

They asked me which of the following factor should not affect loan pricing:

1. credit rating of sponsors;
2. sovereign rating of the host country;
3. interest rate swap counterparty;
4. market pricing.

I went with "sovereign rating of the host country" because I thought it is about government's credit rating which may not affect a bank's loan pricing, but I am not so sure now.

For context, I'm in Australia.

edit: fix spelling errors.